# In Python, I am comparing dataframes containing strings to decide if it should pass or fail. How can I stop data from passing when it should fail?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, contains, tolist

I have over 20 test cases that check a CSV for data anomalies due to data entry. This test case (#15) compares the salutation and addressee to marital status.

```
# Test case  15
# Compares MrtlStat to  PrimAddText and PrimSalText
df = data[data['MrtlStat'].str.contains("Widow|Divorced|Single")]
df = df[df['PrimAddText'].str.contains("AND|&", na=False)]
data_15 = df[df['PrimSalText'].str.contains("AND|&", na=False)]

# Adds row to list of failed data
ids = data_15.index.tolist()

# Keep track of data that failed test case 15 
for i in ids:
  data.at[i,'Test Case Failed']+=', 15'
```

If MrtlStat contains  Widow, Divorced, or Single while PrimAddText or PrimSalTexts contains AND or &, it should fail the test. This test works only if BOTH PrimSalTexts and PrimAddText contain AND or &.

Table showing data that passes but should fail:

| PrimAddText | PrimSalText | MrtlStat |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mrs. Judith Elfrank | Mr. & Mrs. Elfrank & Michael | Widowed |
| Mr. & Mrs.Karl Magnusen | Mr. Magnusen | Widowed |

Table showing data that fails as expected:

| PrimAddText | PrimSalText | MrtlStat |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mr. & Mrs. Elfrank | Mr. & Mrs. Elfrank & Michael | Widowed |

How can I adjust the test to work if only one of the columns (PrimSalTexts or PrimAddText) contains AND or &?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an AND condition b/w the second and third condition, you can separate these out and capturing the result from each condition. finally combine the two lists together

```
# Test case  15
# Compares MrtlStat to  PrimAddText and PrimSalText
df = data[data['MrtlStat'].str.contains("Widow|Divorced|Single")]
data_15_A = df[df['PrimAddText'].str.contains("AND|&", na=False)]
data_15_B = df[df['PrimSalText'].str.contains("AND|&", na=False)]

# Adds row to list of failed data
ids = data_15_A.index.tolist() + data_15_B.index.tolist()

# Keep track of data that failed test case 15 
for i in ids:
  data.at[i,'Test Case Failed']+=', 15'
```

Comment: This is pretty much what I was missing. Only issue is it adds 15 twice to the 'Test Case failed' column.

Answer (score 2):

You should not filter your data sequentially but combine the condition into a single one (using & and |). A good way to do it is numpy.where:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# construct data
data = pd.DataFrame({
    'PrimAddText': ['Mrs. Judith Elfrank', 'Mr. & Mrs.Karl Magnusen', 'Mr. & Mrs. Elfrank'],
    'PrimSalText': ['Mr. & Mrs. Elfrank & Michael', 'Mr. Magnusen', 'Mr. & Mrs. Elfrank & Michael'],
    'MrtlStat': ['Widowed', 'Widowed', 'Widowed']
})

# Case 15 - create condition
data['Status_case15'] = np.where((data['MrtlStat'].str.contains("Widow|Divorced|Single") 
                           & (data['PrimAddText'].str.contains("AND|&", na=False) 
                              | data['PrimSalText'].str.contains("AND|&", na=False))), False, True)
# filter failing rows
data.loc[data['Status_case15'] == False]

# sum correct rows
sum(data['Status_case15'])
```

Comment: Personally, I'd replace `pass/fail` with `True/False`,  This allows for easier counting, indexing, etc.

Comment: This is probably the better approach next script I write, but I would have to adjust 26 different tests to accommodate this.  Naveed's answer is more in line with what I was missing and need. Thank you!